# Character replacement in string: How to do it with regex?

Tags: python, regex, string

I am replacing spaces before interpunction with this - working, but - very unelegant code:

```
my_string = "There , are , many , wrong . spaces , before interpunction  marks !"

my_string.replace(" ,", ",").replace(" .", ".").replace(" !", "!").replace(" ?", "?")
```

Now I tried to come up with a more elegant solution, i.e. a regular expression. But all I got is:

```
import re
my_string = re.sub(r"[\s]+[,.!?]", XXX, my_string)
```

I just don't understand how to make **XXX** replacing each `whitespace+mark` with the corresponding `mark`. OR how to simply strip each whitespace before ALL marks - that would work too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create a capturing group for the punctuation, then refer to that group in the replacement expression:

```
re.sub(r'\s+([,.!?])', r'\1', my_string)
```

You don't need brackets around the `\s`; it is already a character class.

Demonstration:

```
>>> import re
>>> my_string = "There , are , many , wrong . spaces , before interpunction  marks !"
>>> re.sub(r'\s+([,.!?])', r'\1', my_string)
'There, are, many, wrong. spaces, before interpunction  marks!'
```

Comment: I headed back to [docs.python/re](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/re.html), and I see why I couldn't catch it myself... there is no seperate paragraph or anything indicating the importance of '\1'. It is hidden mid-sentence and in the examples...

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture the punctuation using parentheses, then refer to it using `\1`:

```
import re
my_string = "There , are , many , wrong . spaces , before interpunction  marks !"
my_string = re.sub(r"[\s]+([,.!?])", r"\1", my_string)
print my_string  # There, are, many, wrong. spaces, before interpunction  marks!
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a capturing group:

```
[\s]+([,.!?])
```

Then use it in the replacement:

```
\1
```

\n refers to the n-th capturing group, \0 to the whole match.

Answer (score 0):

The last line should be something like:

```
my_string = re.sub(r"\s+([,.!?])", r'\1', my_string)
```

The paranthesises in the pattern-part is making a group and you then refer to that group with `\1` since its the first and only group.